# GridView Sorting without losing user modifications

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a bit of a unique problem. I am using a GridView to display information from a database. The requirements for this GridView are that it is always editable so I have TextBoxes in the ItemTemplates and want to save the values when a button is clicked.

That all works great.

The problem is I am trying to get sorting (and eventually paging) working and hitting problems. If I bind the GridView from an ObjectDataSource this obviously doesn't work because it rebinds the datasource before it sorts and I lose any modified values. If I bind the GridView from a DataTable and try to store it in a Session variable it *still* doesn't work because any modified values aren't in the session variable.

I'm really just looking for suggestions on what I could possibly do to sort (and page later) without losing values the user has modified. I realize most people don't modify the Gridview all at once so its a weird problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement client-side sorting of the GridView which would have the added benefit of making your UI feel faster. There is [a blog post on sorting with jQuery](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2011/01/01/client-side-sorting-in-asp-net-grid-view-using-jquery.aspx) you could try, though I have not personally used the method suggested.

Alternatively, you could send the values back to the server via AJAX while editing and save them (temporarily) in the session, the database, or where it makes the post sense in your scenario. You would obviously need to retrieve them when sorting.

One final option would be to save your values on the postback caused by the sort command. Mostly you would do something along the lines of handling the OnTextChanged event of the TextBoxes and (as above) saving the values to a temporary store. You would not want these TextBoxes to autopostback - they would simply wait for a postback such as the one caused by your sorting event. In this scenario you could also use the temporary store you populate during the save event to avoid duplicating the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had considered saving on Sort which would make things easier but seems very much logically incorrect. A user wouldn't expect a sort to persist data. I will look into the client side sorting with jQuery and mark the answer if it ends up working for me. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @novacara I think whether or not saving on sort makes logical sense depends very strongly on your UI feedback and overall interaction models - think of familiar systems like Gmail and you can recognize that there are cases where constant saving is desirable. However, you may also consider temporarily saving the data without committing it: use an alternate store, flag it, etc, so that the difference is transparent to the user.

Comment: I think I am going to go with the jQuery solution. I'm going to need some additional help tailoring that to my specific gridview since it has actual controls (textbox, checkbox) inside instead of just text but I'll ask a follow up question on that. Thanks for the help!